# ASP.NET MVC View information stored in a data-store

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm looking for some advice on storing views in a data-store (database, file, other) and display them based on routing data, all using ASP.NET MVC 2 and ASP.NET Routing.

For example, I'd like to be able to display different views based on the following route data:

```
/{country}/
/{country}/{area}
```

But in the same vein I'd like to display:

```
/{planet}/
/{planet}/{satellite}
```

All are based on strings, and the data isn't fixed. So based on the number of segments maybe, use that as the selection criteria into the data-store...additionally, I may not know the segments up front, so they'd all be dynamic.

I'm was hoping we could get a few different methods together here, as kind of a reference for all - I'm sure some methods won't suite everyone...

So, how would you do it?

---

[Branislav Abadjimarinov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2217325/asp-net-mvc-view-information-stored-in-a-data-store/2220688#2220688) suggested a Controller Factory which could be used to do the look-up and display the page dynamically. I like this idea, what do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way for MVC to understand from this url's which route to choose. You have to make the routes more specific. For example:

/planet/{planet}/{satelite}

/country/{country}/{area}

You also have the option to define your own [controller factory](http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2008/10/10/asp-net-mvc-tip-dependency-injection-with-structuremap.aspx). The controller factory decides which controller to instantiate based on the route. So you can put some custom logic in it like - check if the {planet} parameter exist and if yes instantiate Planet controller else instantiate Countries controller.

Comment: Ah, so a generic controller could be created by the controller factory to serve the request...I like, thanks!

Comment: Went with the custom controller factory which worked just fine for us, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This [Post](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-03-cs.aspx) could be really helpful for you.

Remember you always can add a new routing rule : )

Just like [this](http://www.asp.net/%28S%28ywiyuluxr3qb2dfva1z5lgeg%29%29/learn/mvc/tutorial-23-cs.aspx)